# Where to initialize store when using connect in react-redux project

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, store

I am new to react and redux so am confused where to initialize store with dummy data? am using provider in the root component .
the only two ways to access store i found are either using this:-

```
Provider.childContextTypes = {
   store: React.PropTypes.object
}
```

or by using connect ,

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
 state:state.contacts
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
 setDummyData: () => dispatch(setDummyData())
});

export default connect(
 mapStateToProps,
 mapDispatchToProps
)(ComponentName)
```

but contacts isn't initialized ..
How to approach?

any any links where i can find examples with connect and dummy data will be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do it either in `createStore` for whole store or in reducer(s) for each slice.

https://redux.js.org/api/createstore

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a `store` in your `index.js` file (for instance if you used `create-react-app`).  Once you initialize your store, you can pass it to your provider and wrap your app with the provider:

```
const = createStore(someReducers, someMiddleWareIfYouHaveIt)
<Provider store={store}>
    <App />
</Provider>
```

There are some starter kits [here](https://reactjs.org/community/starter-kits.html) on the ReactJS website as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help.